# Azure Function - tableService.queryEntities get skipped - node.js

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have a function where I use table storage services, I have no problem in updating data in a azure storage table but I'm unable to use queryEntities.

my code looks like below:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var tableService = azure.createTableService(mystuff,mystuff);
var query = new azure.TableQuery().select(['RowKey']);//or .top(5)

tableService.queryEntities('mytable', query, null, function(error, result, response) {
  if (!error) {
    // result.entries contains entities matching the query
  }
});
```

the table has entries and I need just the RowKey to be pushed in result;

if I place a context.log to check till where it get's executed, I have that:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var tableService = azure.createTableService(mystuff,mystuff);
var query = new azure.TableQuery().select(['RowKey']); //or .top(5)
context.log("control1")
tableService.queryEntities('mytable', query, null, function(error, result, response) {
context.log("control2")
  if (!error) {
    // result.entries contains entities matching the query
  }
});
```

control1 appears in console, the control2 is skipped so I guess the tableService.queryEntities is totally skipped.

all the other tableService methods works without issue, any help?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-nodejs#query-a-set-of-entities

Comment: can you try with
var query = new azure.TableQuery().from('mytable').select(['RowKey']); //or .top(5)

Comment: Hello @houssem, I got "TypeError: (intermediate value).from is not a functionStack"
As per the doc .from is not needed

Comment: I think your this is because your function didn't wait the query, It first do the logic below the query, after instance ended, context log was been closed. At that time, query can't use context log because function instance is ended. You can have a look of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem:

[image]

Simply to explain, this is a async question. Query needs time, the function skip and first do the do the logic below the query.

Solution:

Just wait the query logic finished. Like this:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage')
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    responseMessage = await executeSprocInternal();
    context.res = {
        body: responseMessage
    };
}
async function executeSprocInternal() {
    try {
        var tableService = azure.createTableService('storagename','xxxxxx');
        
    
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var query = new azure.TableQuery().select(['RowKey']); //or .top(5)
            console.log("control1")
            tableService.queryEntities('mytable', query, null, function(error, result, response) {
            console.log("control2")
              if (!error) {
                // result.entries contains entities matching the query
              }
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(2, e)
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            reject(e);
        });
    }
}
```

This time I can success get the console1 and console2:

[image]

Let me know whether this can solved your question.

Comment: Hi Bowman Zhu,
Thank you for your reply, I've tried this in live environment and it's exceeded 5:00:00 run
[Error] Timeout value of 00:05:00 exceeded by function